# ubuntu 20.04 notify-updates-outdated not found

Tags: apt, motd

My problem is that my file is lost! Where I can find it? Can I reinstall it (restore it) as part of a package? Which one?

I  get the following message:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates available exited with return code 127.
```

because:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates: 7: /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdates:not found
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

PS: Sorry for my english... It isn't my first language (it's spanish).

Answer (score 17):

Gustavo, I had the same error with **motd**. I fixed the problem by installing the  **update-notifier-common** package.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is an error in `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates` in line 7. Have you edited the file?

The filename should be: `/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdated`!!

That is, the last letter is a "d" not an "s".