# MOTD display updates can be applied though none is actually available

Tags: server, updates, motd

A few days ago I upgrade my home server from ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 using do-release-upgrade.

The install brokes during the process, but I think I was able to repair (thanks to other posts from here).

However, I have an inconsistent behavior.

The MOTD says I have `470 upgrade that can be applied immediately`.

It suggest to run `apt list --upgradable`, but this command tell every thing is up to date.

What's wrong? how to fix?

If it helps:

```
sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/
cat /run/motd.dynamic.new
```

Outputs:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 21.10 (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-21-generic aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

470 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
```

`sudo apt list --upgradable`outputs `Listing... Done`

`sudo apt update` :

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`uname -a` outputs

```
Linux homeserver 5.13.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 19 09:01:50 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

And finally, `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

Comment: @Nmath: done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I missed an important part in my diagnostic.

`sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/`

Outputs also (missed the latest lines in my copy/paste)

`/etc/update-motd.d//90-updates-available: 7: /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-updates-outdated: not found run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d//90-updates-available exited with return code 127`

This lead to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312090/19845).

Basically, a package was missing (not sure to get why this was missing).

As the other post stated, running `sudo apt install update-notifier-common` solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you. You ended my 2 hours of debugging with a success! :-)

Comment: [I'm having the same problem with MOTD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456325/motd-444-updates-can-be-applied-immediately-apt-list-upgradable-lists-ju), but I'm not missing the mentioned file nor does `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` gives any error.